# Azure App-Insights correlation with chained API Management calls and Spring Boot + Apache HTTP

Tags: spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

I have a public facing API that calls to a backend Web App that, in turn, calls out to another API (in same API Management instance as first API) that makes an external call.

My Web App is a Spring Boot using Apache HTTP client and the SDK is configured for AI, and I can see the AppInsights through to the dependency call. But at this point, the call to the next APIMgmt API creates a new request that is not correlated and shows up as a seperate operation (but with the correct BACKEND event).

I've tried [passing "Request-Id" and "Correlation-Context"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#correlation-headers) (unmodified) from my Apache client to the API. App Insights show up but under the wrong parent and have no BACKEND events.

How can I correlate this chain of events?

Comment: Would you enhance the question title please - to indicate that this question is also related to Apache HTTP / Spring Boot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of testing, debugging and reading. This is doable, but you have to access the RequestTelemetry from within your calling code to get the correct Request-Id header value.

```
    RequestTelemetryContext ctx = ThreadContext.getRequestTelemetryContext();
    RequestTelemetry reqTel = ctx.getHttpRequestTelemetry();
    String currentRequestId = reqTel.getId();
```

Comment: jrobkc, this is accurate. This is exactly how this can be achieved. I would ensure that this is documented on Ms Docs as well.

Comment: @DhavalDoshi - I just noticed in my App Insights that this accurately links the front end of the final API management call, but the BACKEND is missing.

> API1FrontEnd
>  API1Backend
>     AppService1
>         API2FrontEnd
>            MISSING - API2Backend

Comment: Apparently there is an issue with Application Insights (awaiting further documentation from Microsoft) if the Request-Id is too large, the telemetry is rejected. This chain of events is creating an id that qualifies. Tested by passing the expected parent Id manually to API2 Frontend, no insights were logged.

Comment: There was a bug in API management team where they were producing really long id's. Here is the relevant Github issue. https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/693#issuecomment-473011529 I believe the team is rolling out fix soon.

Comment: @DhavalDoshi Thanks! I ran into a problem as well, when I do the above, i lose all my dependencies from the applicationinsights-agent that it was tracking. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DhavalDoshi I figured out the sudden disappearance of my telemetry, it seems the Always On usage with Tomcat does some class caching, which appears to prevent the agent from starting properly. Disabling Auto On and replacing it with an App Insights Availability check and all is working as expected. Thanks for the help!